# Changing Default Checkered Background UI Color

Tags: customization, theme

I was wondering is there anyway to customize the checkerboard color? I'd like to lower it's contrast since it is very distracting for me. I can't seems to find the one attribute in theme preference. I wanted to know if it's possible to change it before filling bug report to blender devs.

*Note that I'm not asking adding custom background for rendering, it's more UI color customization. I do want it to be rendered in transparent, I just dont want it to be showed in lookdev mode.*

Thanks.

[image: How to change checker color?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now the checkerboard color are changeable in theme preferences
under *Preferences > Themes > User Interface > Transparent Checkerboard.*

[image]